# Change size of font incrementally on click

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have searched this database (and the web) but am not having any lucky on the following vba code i would like to write.
I would like to put a button on a form in access which upon clicking increases the size of the font in a certain text box.  Exactly was we have in Excel, PowerPoint, ect..
Any advice on where to start will be greatly appreciated.
Grazie,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A text box's `FontSize` property is a read/write integer.  Since it's writable, your button click could increment the current font size.

```vb
With Me.YourTextBoxName
    .FontSize = .FontSize + 1
End With
```

Comment: Hans, you are a magician..  !Thanks alot..   If you have a chance, why is the WITH operation necessary?

Comment: `WITH` is not necessary, but it avoids using `Me.YourTextBoxName.FontSize` twice.